# Is the smaller companion of Pulsar J0453+1559 still the smallest known neutron star? Was it further confirmed to be a NS after Martinez et al. (2015)?

Tags: observational-astronomy, neutron-star, binary-star, pulsar

@ProfRob's Physics SE [answer to *What is the theoretical lower mass limit for a gravitationally stable neutron star?*](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/143174/83380) was linked just now in their [answer to *Can a neutron star ever be less than about 1.44 solar masses (the Chandrasekhar limit)? Why not?*](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/43989/7982) which notes that a smaller neutron star companion to the J0453+1559 pulsar *might (or might not) be* the smallest currently known pulsar:

> A number of neutron stars in binary systems have measured masses below $1.44 M_\odot$ (e.g. a pulsar of mass $1.251 \pm 0.021 M_\odot$, [McKee et al. 2020](https://arxiv.org/abs/2009.12283)). I think the current lowest mass contender is $1.174 \pm 0.004 M_\odot$ ([Martinez et al. (2015)](http://arxiv.org/abs/1509.08805) *Pulsar J0453+1559: A Double Neutron Star System with a Large Mass Asymmetry*.

The abstract of Martinez et al. (2015) includes the sentence:

> **If this companion is also a neutron star** (NS), as indicated by the orbital eccentricity of the system (e=0.11), then its mass is the smallest precisely measured for any such object.

and Section 3, Results explains:

> Given the orbital eccentricity (e = 0.11), **the companion is very likely to be a neutron star** – if it had evolved into a massive white dwarf star there would be no sudden mass loss associated with a supernova explosion and the system would have retained the circular orbit that is characteristic of compact accreting systems. **This is consistent with the non-detection of an optical counterpart of the system in any of the optical catalogs. However, the high eccentricity does not entirely settle the matter:** the recent discovery of a recycled pulsar with a massive (∼ 1M⊙) companion PSR J1727−2946 [Lorimer et al. (2015)](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2015MNRAS.450.2185L/abstract) and an orbital eccentricity of 0.0456 bridges the previously observed eccentricity gap between systems with NS and massive WD companions. **In the remainder of this paper we will assume, with caution, that the companion is a NS.**

That the companion may be a neutron star is important for this analysis; the next sentence is

> The pulsar’s orbital eccentricity allows a detection of the advance of periastron, ˙ω. **If
> both components are compact, as implied by the optical non-detection,** this is given by:
>
> $$\dot{\omega} = \dot{\omega}_{GR} + \dot{\omega}_{K}$$
>
> [...]

And the conclusion section notes that this is a relatively small eccentricity for double neutron stars listed in Table 1 *as of 2015.*

---

It's now been six years, so I'd like to ask:

**Question:** Has the smaller companion to Pulsar J0453+155 been confirmed to be a neutron star by any further work beyond that of Martinez et al. (2015) and is it still the smallest known neutron star?

Has the smaller companion to Pulsar J0453+155 been confirmed to be a neutron star after Martinez et al. (2015) and is it still the smallest known neutron star?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a picture from the most recent review I could find - [Horvath et al. (2020)](https://arxiv.org/abs/2011.08157).

The companion of J0453+1559 is still the least massive of the double neutron stars with very precisely measured masses. I cannot find any citations to the Martinez et al. paper ([here is a list](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2015ApJ...812..143M/citations)) that either update the mass or shed any further light on its true identity. It appears to have been accepted in the literature as a neutron star - though there is still a school of thought that it could yet be a massive white dwarf ([Tauris & Janka 2019](https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.12318)).

As you can see from the picture there are several other objects with only slightly higher masses, and some of these are pulsars and are unambiguously neutron stars (e.g. a pulsar of mass $1.251 \pm 0.021 M_\odot$, [McKee et al. 2020](https://arxiv.org/abs/2009.12283)). There are some neutron stars in X-ray binaries and with white dwarf companions that *may* have a lower mass; but the uncertainties could push them above J0453+1559.

[image: from Horvath et al. (2020)]

Comment: Quite an impressive collection, and quite a nice summary of the state of the situation, *thanks!*